# How To Provide Search-As-You-Type Filtering With UICollectionView?

Tags: uitextfield, uisearchbar, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView added to a ViewController.  The UICollectionView displays a grid of items with peoples names on each cell.
I would like to add search as you type functionality that will filter the UICollectionView as the user types in their name to a searchbar or UITextField on the ViewController so that it doesn't scroll with the content in the UICollectionView.

Even though a few places I have read that UICollectionView is similar to UITableView I don't see that implementing this filter/search functionality is the same in UICollectionView as it is with UITableView and need some help with it.

Does anyone have a good example of doing this search/filter as you type functionality with UICollectionView?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Try to investigate search in TableView, understand UISearchBar and change to UICollectionView. Please try and make another detail Question if you meet problem.

Comment: Can someone explain how to do this? I still don't know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by doing the following (hope it helps somebody else):

I populate my UICollectionView from CoreData into an NSArray:

```
self.allCVData = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

then add my NSArray to an NSMutableArray so that I can use that for filtering on the UICollection:

```
self.filteredCVData =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:allCVData];
```

Added a UITextField and called it searchField.

Added a selector in viewDidLoad:

```
[mytextfield addTarget:self action:@selector(textDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Added a method to accept changes in the UITextField:

```
-(void) textDidChange:(id)sender
{

    UITextField* searchField = (UITextField *) sender;

    if(searchField.text.length == 0)
    {
        self.isFiltered = FALSE;
        [self.filteredCVData removeAllObjects];
        [self.filteredCVData addObjectsFromArray:self.allCVData];
    }
    else
    {
        self.isFiltered = true;
        [self.filteredCVData removeAllObjects];
        self.filteredCVData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        LogInfo(@"Before Looping in allCVData Array.");
        for (OLPerson* person in allCVData)
        {
            NSRange firstnameRange = [person.firstname rangeOfString:searchField.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            NSRange surnameRange = [person.surname rangeOfString:searchField.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if(firstnameRange.location != NSNotFound || surnameRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [self.filteredCVData addObject:person];
            }
        }
    }

    [self.collectionView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to manually remove some UICollectionViewCell? In my app, I only changed datasource and it crashes sometimes.

Comment: @lenhhoxung I do use a custom UICollectionViewCell in my UICollectionView.  What do you mean when you say "manually remove"?

Comment: Yes, I used a custom UICollectionViewCell. I mean that I only need to change datasource (array) then call realoadData on UICollectionView to change number of cells. It works, but sometimes it crashes.

Comment: Something like:
2014-01-08 01:38:47.004 Benbi[5441:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (26) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (37) ...